# Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference? while using PasswordEncoder

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig  {


    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .build();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

while running above code i got error Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference? using PasswordEncoder Bean why it i got this error how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circular dependency occurs as follows:

1. The `SecurityConfig` class has a dependency on the `UserDetailsService` bean, which is likely provided by Spring Security.
2. The `UserDetailsService` bean requires the `PasswordEncoder` bean to encode and decode passwords for authentication.
3. The `PasswordEncoder` bean, in turn, depends on the `SecurityConfig` class to create the `AuthenticationManager`.

This creates a cycle in the dependency graph, leading to the circular reference error.

To solve this error, you can break the circular dependency by making some changes to the code:

1. Move the `PasswordEncoder` bean creation to a separate `@Configuration` class. This way, it won't be involved in the circular reference.

   @Configuration
   public class PasswordEncoderConfig {
   @Bean
   PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
   return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
   }
2. Remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the `configureGlobal` method in the `SecurityConfig` class. Spring will automatically inject the `UserDetailsService` into the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` without the need for explicit `@Autowired`.

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class SecurityConfig  {

   ```
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    // ... (other methods)

    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    // ... (other methods)
   ```

   }

By separating the `PasswordEncoder` bean into its configuration class and removing the `@Autowired` from the `configureGlobal` method, you should be able to resolve the circular dependency issue and avoid the "Requested bean is currently in creation" error. Remember to check other parts of your codebase to ensure there are no other circular dependencies that could lead to similar issues.

Comment: It worked, after i removed @Autowired annotation it solve circular dependency error.

Comment: Hi, Shavarsh Shahoyan.  

Most or all of your 9 answers over the last few weeks appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.